Growth of invariants in mod-$p$ representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n$
Let $G$ be smooth admissible mod-$p$ representations of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$. Also suppose $\pi$ is an irreducible infinite-dimensional smooth admissible representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.  If $K_m$ is the principal congruence subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ of level $p^m$, what is the asymptotic growth rate of $\dim_{\mathbb{F}_p} \pi^{K_m}$ as $m$ tends to infinity?
My current intuition suggests a potential connection between the growth rate and the Gelfand-Kirillov dimension of the dual representation $\pi^\vee$ as a module over the Iwasawa algebra $\Lambda_{\mathbb{F}_p} = \mathbb{F}_p[[SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)]]$. The Gelfand-Kirillov dimension, a non-commutative analogue of Krull dimension, provides a measure of the "size" or complexity of a module over a non-commutative ring.
In the characteristic zero setting, a relationship between the growth of invariants and the Gelfand-Kirillov dimension is known for certain classes of representations. This suggests a similar connection might exist in the mod-$p$ case. Also the dual representation $\pi^\vee$ naturally carries a $\Lambda_{\mathbb{F}_p}$-module structure. The growth of invariants can be interpreted as the growth of the dimension of the fixed points under the action of successively smaller subgroups of $SL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$. This growth might be controlled by the "size" of $\pi^\vee$ as a $\Lambda_{\mathbb{F}_p}$-module, which is captured by its Gelfand-Kirillov dimension.
However, the precise nature of this relationship, especially in the mod-$p$ setting, where the representation theory is more intricate due to the presence of non-semisimple modules, is still unclear to me.

See section 2.4 of (https://math.uchicago.edu/~emerton/pdffiles/capture_final_final.pdf) and p. 17 of (http://www.davidrenshawhansen.net/solidjacquetlanglands.pdf).
